# Is there a work around to reference a variable above where its declared

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

So I'm building a template with handlebars and I want to append const totalSum to const sumTextSidebar. But obviously it can't find it bc it hasn't been created yet. Is there a workaround for this? I included my code below. Thank you!

```
function multi(element) {
  const responseSidebar = ($(element).data('sidebar-respond'));
  const responseUnder = ($(element).data('response-under'));
  const optionId = Number($(element).data('optionid')) + 1;
  const questionId = $(element).data('questionid') + 1;
  const responseUnderArea = '#quiz-alert-' + questionId;
  const sidebarId = '#sidebar-' + (questionId - 1) + '-' + (optionId - 1);
  const sidebarQuestion = '#sidebar-' + (questionId - 1);
  const responseUnderID = "#" + (questionId - 1) + "-" + (optionId - 1);
  const sumTextUnderQuestionID = '#sumTextUnder-' + (questionId - 1);
  **const sumTextSidebar** = ($(element).data('sumTextSidebar')+ totalSum);
  const sumSidebarElement = $('<li>' + sumTextSidebar + '</li>');
  const values = Number($(element).val());
  const sumSidebarId = '#sumTextID-' + questionId;

  if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
    $(sidebarId).removeClass('hidden');
    $(responseUnderID).removeClass('hidden');
    $(responseUnderArea).removeClass('hidden');
    $(sumTextUnderQuestionID).removeClass('hidden');
    if ($(sumSidebarId).length == 0) {
      $(sidebarQuestion).append(sumSidebarElement).slideDown('slow');
      sumSidebarElement.attr('id', 'sumTextID-' + questionId);
    }
    addValue.push(values)
  } else {
    $(sidebarId).addClass('hidden');
    $(responseUnderID).addClass('hidden');
    subtractValue.push(values)
  }

  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  const addValueSum = addValue.reduce(getSum);
  const subtractValueSum = subtractValue.reduce(getSum);
  **const totalSum** = addValueSum - subtractValueSum;
```

Comment: Actually, you can reference a variable prior to its declaration due to hoisting.

Comment: Not when you're using const/let, it doesn't hoist.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying `to append const totalSum to const sumTextSidebar`? I don't see it in your code

Comment: Sorry, it's not included but it would be this                                              
 const sumTextSidebar = ($(element).data('sumTextSidebar')+ totalSum);

Comment: So sumTextSidebar is text saying' the sum of your choice is:'.  totalSum is the calculated amount based on the if/else statement. This entire function is a click event.

Comment: I might not understand your problem completely, but I don't see anything wrong with moving the `const sumTextSidebar = ($(element).data('sumTextSidebar')+ totalSum);` bit of code below `const totalSum = addValueSum - subtractValueSum;`

Comment: The thing with that is then the if statement errors out bc sumSidebarElement references sumTextSidebar which is referenced in the if statement.

Comment: Instead of interacting with the `sumSideBarElement` in that if statement, create another variable and set it to true/false and then do that later on based on that value. `let noSumSideBar = false;` then in the if statement `noSumSideBar = true` then later in the code `if (noSumSideBar) { slideDown stuff }`

Comment: oof i see how that is problematic too because you moify addValues... your code is _really_ complex with all of these variables running around

Comment: Yeah I think I might try appending that value in a different way instead of trying to float it up. Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it!